# Why can't I bind to my foreground service twice from the same object?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-service

I have an object in app A that implements `IServiceConnection` which binds to a foreground `Service` in a different app (app B):

```
public class MyServiceConnection : Java.Lang.Object, IServiceConnection
{
    private IBinder _binder;
    private TaskCompletionSource<bool> _connectTcs;

    public MyServiceConnection()
    {
        BeginConnect();
    }

    public void BeginConnect() => ConnectAsync().ContinueWith(EndConnect);

    public Task<bool> ConnectAsync(CancellationToken ct = default)
    {
        if (_connectTcs?.IsCompleted ?? true)
        {
            _connectTcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
            ct.Register(() => _connectTcs.TrySetCanceled(ct));

            var package = "com.sample.appb";
            var componentName = new Componentname(package, $"{package}.ServiceInB");

            var service = new Intent().SetComponent(componentName);
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                Application.Context.StartForegroundService(service);
            }
            else
            {
                Application.Context.StartService(service);
            }

            Application.Context.BindService(service, this, Bind.AutoCreate);
        }

        return await _connectTcs;
    }

    private void EndConnect(Task task)
    {
        // handle task result
    }

    public void OnServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service)
    {
        _binder = service;
    }

    public void OnServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name)
    {
        _binder = null;
    }

    // methods that are called on the service
}
```

When the object is created, I bind to the `Service` and it is successful. When app B crashes or I call `am force-stop` on app B, `OnServiceDisconnected()` gets called, which is expected. I handle the lost connection by connecting again, but on the second connection `OnServiceConnected()` never gets called, so I never get my `IBinder` object to call methods on. If I restart app A I can perform a single bind again. How do I properly get the `Service` binder multiple times during one run time?

Comment: You mean that you want to connect service when disconnect? where do you handle the lost connection by connecting again?

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT besides the constructor, in each of the methods referenced at the bottom of the class I call `ConnectAsync` if `_binder` is `null`. The intention is to restart app B before attempting to transact on that service. The app starts and the bind method returns true, but `OnServiceConnected` does not get called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue, I split the original object into two objects: One that inherits from `IServiceConnection` and holds the `IBinder` from the service, and another that holds instances of these. When the holder needs to connect, it first disposes any held instance of the `IServiceConnection`, then calls `Context.BindService()` with a new instance. When the holder needs to disconnect, it calls `Context.UnbindService()`, then disposes the `IServiceConnection` instance.